# Loop through array with arrays using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a `var` which contains an array with multiple arrays. And I am trying to get the values of each cell in order to print them into an HTML table.

I'd like to use a foreach but since I have no idea how to do it, even though I've seen examples on internet, I tried to do this using a for loop. But I cannot make it work.

Is there an easier way to do this?.

this is the code I have:

```
    var DetalleFactura=response[0]['DetalleFactura']; //var with the array I'd like to print

    for(int i = 0; i < DetalleFactura.length;i++){

        var value = parent[i];

        for(int j = 0; j < parent[i].length; j++){

        /*print values here*/

        }
```

Comment: Please the post example array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your question here's how you can print the values like you indicated using forEach.

```
DetalleFactura.forEach((subArr)=>{
subArr.forEach(val => {
console.log(val);
   })
});
```

You can also just use array.flat() to get the results you want.

```
const flatArr = DetalleFactura.flat();
```

[Array.prototype.flat documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Comment: what if I want to get the data based on the row instead of cell? Supposing each array within the parent array is a row from database

Comment: @ErrolChavesMoya can you explain your use case a little bit more, I think there is some confusion here on what you want to achieve

Comment: @chairmanmow thanks, it woked. But I had to modify your answer to do what I wanted

Comment: @moronator nevermind I solved it already Thanks for your help. I just had to remove the second forEach of this answer to make it work like this: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/1wk6xhdt/)

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide an example array, it's hard to help with your specific problem but assuming you have a n-dimensional array it could look something like this:

```js
var DetalleFactura=[0, [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, [6, 7, 8]]]

function printArray(arr){
  for(var item of arr){
    if(typeof(item) == 'object') printArray(item)
    else console.log(item)
  }
}
printArray(DetalleFactura)
```

If you want to learn more about for-loops like this you may read [this mozilla article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Comment: It is not two-dimensional it can be whatever dimension the user want.

Comment: Then you should take a look at recursion

Comment: Edited to print a n-dimensional array now

Comment: what if I want to get the data based on the row instead of cell? Supposing each array within the parent array is a row from database